# What is cpu_entry_area?

Tags: linux-kernel, memory, 64bit

The documentation of the Linux kernel describes the [virtual memory map](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/x86_64/mm.txt).

It says:

> `fffffe0000000000 - fffffe7fffffffff (=39 bits) cpu_entry_area mapping`

What is this "cpu entry area"? Is it accessible in some way to code running in [ring 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protection_ring) (i.e. CPL3)?

I ask because I am experimenting with QEMU, and it seems that some CPL3 code that runs on the QEMU guest (Ubuntu server 18.04) attempts (I don't know whether it succeeds) to access memory in `cpu_entry_area`.
At first, I thought I did something wrong, as I thought that all addresses higher than `0x00007fffffffffff` aren't accessible to CPL3, but then I found out about `vsyscall` (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19938324/5728089)).

I tried to access `vsyscall` memory (specifically `*(int *)0xffffffffff600000`) from CPL3 code in the QEMU guest, and succeeded, but I got a segfault when I tried to access the `cpu_entry_area` (specifically `*(int *)0xfffffe0000000ee0`).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`cpu_entry_area` contains all the data and code needed to allow the CPU to hand control over to the kernel. When KPTI is enabled, only that part of the kernel is mapped when user-space is running. You can see its definition in [`arch/x86/include/asm/cpu_entry_area.h`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/include/asm/cpu_entry_area.h): it contains

- the GDT;
- the entry stack;
- the TSS;
- a set of trampolines;
- the exception stacks;
- debug stores and buffers.

The trampolines contain the entry points for syscalls; see for example [`arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/arch/x86/entry/entry_64.S) which defines the entry point for 64-bit calls.

None of this is accessible directly from ring 3, but ring 3 code can jump into it using CPU-mediated mechanisms which allow changing privilege levels (*e.g.* the `SYSCALL` CPU instruction).

The kernel documentation on [Page Table Isolation](https://docs.kernel.org/arch/x86/pti.html) provides more context.

Comment: That's very helpful, especially [Documentation/x86/pti.txt](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/x86/pti.txt). But why doesn't `cpu_entry_area` appear when I do [`cat /proc/<pid>/maps`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html), while `vsyscall` does appear?

Comment: `/proc/<pid>/maps` only shows mappings of areas which are accessible from user-space; `vsyscall` is, but the rest of the kernel mappings aren’t. (User-space can jump into `cpu_entry_area`, but that’s mediated by CPU-provided mechanisms for changing privilege levels; `cpu_entry_area` isn’t directly accessible.)

Comment: Cool :)  Any guess for the cause of the trace I got from QEMU? Is there any reason for CPL3 code to try to access `cpu_entry_area`? (Of course, it could be that some bug in my patch of QEMU makes it only seem that way, but I couldn't find such bug..)

Comment: I imagine that a `SYSCALL` could look like a CPL3 access to `cpu_entry_area`, depending on how you’re tracing; likewise an `INT 0x80`... But that’s just guessing ;-).